# Can you put a period after a quote?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, periods

Albert Einstein once said:

> “Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. The important thing is not to stop questioning.”

With quotations, can you put a period after the quotation marks?

Answer (score 0):

Take the period out after the quotation marks, and you're good to go. (Leave the one before the final quotation mark.) Also, you need a comma after "said" and no space after the first quotation mark.

Albert Einstein once said, “Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. The important thing is not to stop questioning.”

Comment: Hello, Adam. This question is not suitable for ELU; for one thing, it shows no sign of research. // The 'comma before the opening quote marks' rule has been replaced in many writers' opinion by 'use a comma, colon, or zero punctuation as you deem appropriate'. This has been covered here before.